# Not able to resolve the XSS cross site scripting vulnerabilitiues

Tags: apache

> I added the below lines in my apache/conf/httpd.conf file to resolve
>   the XSS cross site scripting vulnerabilities.

1)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    #                           (1)    (2)
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

    # `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however,
    # the `X-XSS-Protection` response header should be sent only for
    # HTML documents and not for the other resources.

    <FilesMatch "\.(%FilesMatchPattern%)$">
        Header unset X-XSS-Protection
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>

2 ) header always set x-xss-protection "1; mode=block"


3) <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

> restarted the apache server using the below command
>
> httpd -k restart

But none of them got worked , still the IBM BAVA security scan is showing that (Cross-Site Scripting) is POSITIVE and web server vulnerability is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of the X-XSS-protection header is a feature that notifies you to work with client browsers. Also, it doesn't work at all unless your browser supports it.
This does not help address XSS vulnerabilities on the server side.

Please refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection).

Comment: Any method we have to stop this vulnerabilities from server side?.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to stop an XSS attack with just an apache setting. Web fire barriers, source codes, library, filter, or other means to prevent it as much as possible.